# Sending asynchronous PDU response with cloudhopper

Tags: java, multithreading, smpp

I have project with uses Cloudhopper 5.0.6 library to hold SMPP connection (3.4 version) and send or receive PDUs. 
I need to modify default PDUResopnse so, customized PDU processing was organized by extending DefaultSmppSessionHandler following way:

```
 public class SmppSessionHandlerController extends DefaultSmppSessionHandler {

    @Override
    public PduResponse firePduRequestReceived(PduRequest pduRequest) {
        PduRequestHandler pduReqHandler = pduRequestHandler;
        PduResponse resultPduResponse = pduRequest.createResponse();
        return processDefaultPduResponse(resultPduResponse);
    }

    private PduResponse processDefaultPduResponse(PduResponse pduResponse) {
        //do some transformations here on pduResponse...
        return pduResponse;
    }
 }
```

It works fine only for purposes:

1. Change result command status or some pdu fields / tlv params
2. Don't send any response for current PDU request. To do that *firePduRequestReceived* method must return **null**.

Now I need to add delayed PDU response sending, here the problems began.
My first try was like that:

```
    @Override
    public PduResponse firePduRequestReceived(PduRequest pduRequest) {
        PduRequestHandler pduReqHandler = pduRequestHandler;
        PduResponse resultPduResponse = pduRequest.createResponse();
        return processDefaultPduResponse(resultPduResponse);
    }

    private PduResponse processDefaultPduResponse(PduResponse pduResponse) {
        try {
                Thread.sleep(responseDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Response delay interrupted", e);
            }
        return pduResponse;
    }
```

Sleep for current thread was added to delay sending response, so invocation thread was held for *responseDelay* milliseconds. This works fine if no more requests are coming at the same time for this session. Adding some submit_sm load in same session caused error:

```
com.cloudhopper.smpp.type.SmppTimeoutException: Unable to get response within [10000 ms]
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppSession.sendRequestAndGetResponse(DefaultSmppSession.java:471) ~[ch-smpp-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppSession.enquireLink(DefaultSmppSession.java:439) ~[ch-smpp-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
```

After searching in coudhopper sources I found the problem, it was excusive window lock for any action in DefaultSmppSession class:

```
 future = sendWindow.offer(pdu.getSequenceNumber(), pdu, timeoutMillis, configuration.getRequestExpiryTimeout(), synchronous);
```

The problem was in *com.cloudhopper.commons.util.windowing.Window* class which uses exclusive lock for performing any operations, so it was impossible to wait before returning PRUResponse in one thread and making request from another.

Next try was around returning **null** as request processing (to drop request without sending any response) and sending PDUResponse manually with *com.cloudhopper.smpp.SmppSession.sendResponsePdu(pduResponse)* method. This approach works for awhile but always ends up with following exception:

```
com.cloudhopper.smpp.type.SmppChannelException: null
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppSession.sendResponsePdu(DefaultSmppSession.java:581) ~[ch-smpp-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
    at com.svzn.autotest.smppclient.impl.cloudhopper.SmppSendingManager.sendPduResponse(SmppSendingManager.java:84) ~[smpp-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.svzn.autotest.smppclient.impl.cloudhopper.util.SendPduCommand.sendPduResponse(SendPduCommand.java:80) [smpp-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.svzn.autotest.smppclient.impl.cloudhopper.SmppClientImpl.sendPduResponse(SmppClientImpl.java:91) [smpp-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.svzn.autotest.example.testng_aggr.lib.smpp.event.BaseEventProcessor$1.run(BaseEventProcessor.java:62) [test-classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_37]
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutException: null
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler.<clinit>(WriteTimeoutHandler.java:79) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.createSession(DefaultSmppClient.java:259) ~[ch-smpp-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.doOpen(DefaultSmppClient.java:226) ~[ch-smpp-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.bind(DefaultSmppClient.java:193) ~[ch-smpp-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
    at com.svzn.autotest.smppclient.impl.cloudhopper.tasks.RebindTask.run(RebindTask.java:37) ~[smpp-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoo

lExecutor.java:204) [na:1.6.0_37

]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Have no idea how to fix this error or send asynchronus PDUResponse in same session another way. 
Do you have any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. Issue was in incorrect synchronization block, which blocked parallel asyncronus event processing (sending pdu responses) and processing requests and responses without dealy in usual way.

Its perfectly ok to invoke
*com.cloudhopper.smpp.SmppSession.sendResponsePdu(pduResponse)* 
method in one thread and woking with requests and responses by extending *DefaultSmppSessionHandler* from another one. Everything'll be processed in same session.

**UPDATE:**
Here's the implementation which I used to handle pdu requests:

```
public class SmppSessionHandlerController extends DefaultSmppSessionHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SmppSessionHandlerController.class);

    private volatile PduHandler pduHandler;
private PduResponseHandler pduResponseHandler;
private PduRequestHandler pduRequestHandler;

public SmppSessionHandlerController() {
    super(log);
}

public PduHandler getPduHandler() {
    return pduHandler;
}

public void setPduHandler(PduHandler pduHandler) {
    this.pduHandler = pduHandler;
}

public PduResponseHandler getPduResponseHandler() {
    return pduResponseHandler;
}

public void setPduResponseHandler(PduResponseHandler pduResponseHandler) {
    this.pduResponseHandler = pduResponseHandler;
}

public PduRequestHandler getPduRequestHandler() {
    return pduRequestHandler;
}

public void setPduRequestHandler(PduRequestHandler pduRequestHandler) {
    this.pduRequestHandler = pduRequestHandler;
}

@Override
public void fireExpectedPduResponseReceived(PduAsyncResponse pduAsyncResponse) {
    log.trace("Handling response PDU: {}", pduAsyncResponse);
    pduAsyncResponse.getResponse().setReferenceObject(pduAsyncResponse.getRequest().getReferenceObject());
    processPduResponse(pduAsyncResponse.getResponse());
}


@Override
public void fireUnexpectedPduResponseReceived(PduResponse pduResponse) {
    log.warn("Handling unexpected response PDU: {}", pduResponse);
    processPduResponse(pduResponse);
}

@Override
public boolean firePduReceived(Pdu pdu) {
    PduHandler currPduHandler = pduHandler;
    if (currPduHandler != null) {
        SmppPdu smppPdu = PduToApiConverter.convertToApiObject(pdu);
        currPduHandler.handlePduReceived(smppPdu);
    }
    // default handling is to accept pdu for processing up chain
    return true;
}

public void firePduRequestExpired(PduRequest pduRequest) {
    super.firePduRequestExpired(pduRequest);
}

private void processPduResponse(PduResponse pduResponse) {
    HandlersContextHelper referenceObj = (HandlersContextHelper) pduResponse.getReferenceObject();
    if (referenceObj != null) {
        referenceObj.getSequenceIdHolder().addReceivedSequenceId(pduResponse.getSequenceNumber());
    }
    PduResponseHandler pduRespHandler = pduResponseHandler;
    if (pduRespHandler != null) {
        SmppPduResponse smppPduResponse = PduToApiConverter.convertToApiResponse(pduResponse);
        if (smppPduResponse != null) {
            pduRespHandler.handlePduResponse(smppPduResponse);
        }
    }
    if (referenceObj != null) {
        referenceObj.getSequenceIdHolder().checkSentAndReceivedClosed();
    }
}

@Override
public PduResponse firePduRequestReceived(PduRequest pduRequest) {
    PduRequestHandler pduReqHandler = pduRequestHandler;
    PduResponse resultPduResponse = pduRequest.createResponse();
    if (pduReqHandler == null) {
        return resultPduResponse;
    }
    PduResponse defaultPduResponse = pduRequest.createResponse();
    SmppPduRequest smppPduRequest = PduToApiConverter.convertToApiRequest(pduRequest);
    SmppPduResponse defaultSmppPduResponse = PduToApiConverter.convertToApiResponse(defaultPduResponse);
    if (smppPduRequest == null || defaultSmppPduResponse == null) {
        return resultPduResponse;
    }
    SmppPduResponse resultSmppPduResponse = pduReqHandler.handlePduRequest(smppPduRequest, defaultSmppPduResponse);
    if (resultSmppPduResponse == null) {
        return null;
    }
    PduResponse convertedPduResponse = ApiToPduConverter.convertToPduResponse(resultSmppPduResponse);
    if (convertedPduResponse == null) {
        return resultPduResponse;
    }
    if (!resultPduResponse.getClass().isAssignableFrom(convertedPduResponse.getClass())) {
        return resultPduResponse;
    }
    return convertedPduResponse;
}
}
```

Wich is added to clowdhopper smpp client like this

```
SmppSession session = smppClient.bind(SmppSessionConfiguration_instance, SmppSessionHandlerController_instance );
```

I defined custom interfaces for PduHandler PduRequestHandler and PduResponseHandler which handle special cases of smpp events, you can see that SmppSessionHandlerController just delegate invocations to one of them.

Using method

```
public PduResponse firePduRequestReceived(PduRequest pduRequest)
```

defiend in SmppSessionHandler you can send any response you want in synch mode. If you want to do this in asynch mode, return null pduResponse and use SmppSession.sendResponsePdu(Pdu) instead from current or any other thread.

Comment: Sorry I have question. Lets say during using firePduRequestReceived method, some exception occurred(lets say during saving to db). And I want to force server to resend it later to me. How should I set pduresponse or throw an exception? Can you please help on this?

Comment: You souldn't throw an exception, otherwise it will be handled by netty and server won't be informed in proper way. You should send properly formed pdu response to inform server that resending is required. Response format can be specific and depends on your server.